# Disabling Razor Instrumentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to disable page instrumentation in Razor? I'm having an issue where I'm trying to set a razor template delegate in _AppStart and then use it on other pages. It would work fine, except instrumentation retains a reference in BeginContext/EndContext to _AppStart which blows up on other pages.

For example:

```
// TemplateHolder.cs
public static class TemplateHolder
{
    public static Func<object, object> TheTemplate = null;
}

@* _AppStart.cshtml *@
@{
    TemplateHolder.TheTemplate = @<b>the template</b>;
}

@* OtherPage.cshtml *@
@TemplateHolder.TheTemplate(Model);
```

Everything will appear to work fine until you try to render the template in OtherPage.cshtml, upon which you'll get errors from inside instrumentation trying to get a HttpContext for the _AppStart.

It's easy enough to fix this with a smattering of reflection:

```
static readonly PropertyInfo _instrumentationService = typeof(WebPageExecutingBase).GetProperty("InstrumentationService", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
static readonly PropertyInfo _isAvailableProperty = typeof(InstrumentationService).GetProperty("IsAvailable");

public static void DisableInstrumentation(this WebPageExecutingBase page)
{
    _isAvailableProperty.SetValue(_instrumentationService.GetValue(page), false);
}
```

... which keeps the BeginContext/EndContext calls from being rendered.

But wasn't the whole point of Razor to be object oriented and configurable? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Interesting question but could you not achieve what you want using partial views, custom html helpers or display templates?

Comment: The reason I went this route was to provide easy extensibility for a NuGet module. Want to change what's rendered at a certain point? Just set that template to a new one. Works fine in ViewStart.cshtml, but then you're running code on _every single page_ when you could just set it up once if AppStart.cshtml worked.

Certainly I could make people pass a path to a partial view, but that's way less usable than a simple Settings.Template = @<razor stuff>.

Comment: Why not following the same approach as with the layout, setting a partial view on _ViewStart? You can easily change that by setting another partial, and you can even change it only in particular views. Also if I am not wrong, changes in the AppStart will restart the app as if you change web.config, something that wouldn't happen using another approach like the _ViewStart.

Comment: As I said before, with ViewStart you're running code on every page rather than one. You're also setting things on statics, which may have concurrency issues.

It'd be far better to be able to set something on app start. Restarts of app are irrelevant (and probably desired).

Why can't this work? It'd be trivial to do -- it's just a broken Razor implementation and/or bug that's causing this issue.